# Aperture size for maximum diffraction

Tags: waves, diffraction

When a wave diffracts past an object, diffraction is greatest when the size of the gap is of the same order as the wavelength. However, is it maximised by the condition of the gap being equal to the wavelength?

I'm struggling to find a definitive answer to this in my textbook, and I can't find anything explicit in this [hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/sound/diffrac.html) page either.

What relationship of aperture size to wavelength gives the greatest diffraction?

Comment: How do you define "greatest diffraction"? Angle of deflection? Angle-weighted power? ...?

Comment: The greatest 'bending' of the wave

Comment: I'm sorry but that is not a very good definition. The first maximum of the diffracted wave will be displaced more when the aperture is smaller; there is no limit to that. But of course there will be less total power transmitted. So you really need to be more specific in your definition. Unless the answer "the smallest aperture gives the greatest diffraction" is sufficient for you.

Comment: I'm going off the knowledge I have from my textbook. I'm not interested in the power of the wave, just the wavefront.

Comment: E.g With a larger gap, the wavefront is only slightly 'bent', whereas with a gap equal to the wavelength, the wavefront is circular

Comment: In diffraction, the lateral momentum (initially zero in a plane wave) is altered by the Fourier transform of the real-space aperture. Start there.

Comment: @JonCuster You've _completely_ lost me there. I'm coming at this from an AS level physics perspective.

Comment: @NoahP - well, that makes your goal more difficult, to be sure. Does your textbook go in to why the wave diffracts? But, in any event, the smaller the aperture, the greater the angular spread of the wave on the other side.

Comment: There's no limit to that? E.g for a wave of wavelength 1 metre, an aperture of 1 millimetre would be more effective than one of 0.5 metres? And no, it doesn't go into that. @JonCuster

Comment: Indeed, there is no limit. The smaller the aperture, the more perfectly it starts to look like a point source. Of course the total energy will become less - but the wave front becomes more and more curved.

Comment: Okay, thanks. If you wrote an answer to this effect, I'd be happy to take it as the accepted answer

Comment: Note that it is not true that a gap size equal to a wavelength produces circular wavefronts.   Is that what your book says?

Comment: @garyp No, it says more circular